# disable ssh public key auth when user is expired

Tags: ubuntu, openssh, sshd, key-authentication

Environment is Ubuntu Bionic LTS, I have local user account which is expired, i.e.

```
# chage -l user-test
Last password change                    : Apr 28, 2021
Password expires                    : never
Password inactive                   : never
Account expires                     : Feb 01, 2022
Minimum number of days between password change      : 0
Maximum number of days between password change      : 99999
Number of days of warning before password expires   : 7
```

then that user cannot login via ssh from another machine if using password auth, but if ssh public keys are used  then that user can login.

Where/how can I reconfigure sshd to not allow login for such user also when public key auth method is used? For reference this is the current sshd config:

```
# grep -v ^# /etc/ssh/sshd_config  | uniq
PermitRootLogin yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
UsePAM yes
X11Forwarding yes
PrintMotd no
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

Comment: Things like account expiration are handled by the PAM stack (Plugable Authentication Modules).  You might try comparing `/etc/pam.d/sshd` to `/etc/pam.d/login` to see if there are relevant differences between the two subsystems.

Comment: AFAICS the expired accounts are handled in `/etc/pam.d/common-account` but both `/etc/pam.d/sshd` and `/etc/pam.d/login` are referencing/including it in the same way:

    # grep  common-account sshd login 
    sshd:@include common-account
    login:@include common-account

any other hint?

Comment: I got nothing then.  Sorry.